# DATEDIF() not returning expected value, how can I calculate age in months?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, date

I'm trying to calculate the age of my credit card accounts in Excel. I've read online to use the DATEDIF() function, however, I'm not getting the expected result and I'm not sure where I screwed up.

The formula entered is `=DATEDIF(C2,TODAY(),"m")`
The contents of C2 are `=DATE(2010,6,8)`

For some reason it's returning some random day in 1900 instead of the months since opening. Any help is appreciated.

[image: Result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that cell D4 is set to be displayed[1] as "Date":
 change it to any number format and you will see "94".

*(Select the cell, hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and hit <kbd>1</kbd> then click on "Number" in the dialog)*

[1] The calculated value is there, 4/3 is the 94:th day of a year. Year "0" is 1900.

Answer (score 0):

```
06/08/2010      92
```

Nothing wrong with the Formula you have used `=DATEDIF(C2,TODAY(),"m")`.

Simply place the Cell pointer on Cell D2.

Right Click the Mouse and hit Format Cell command from poped up menu.

Apply the GENERAL format on D2.

You get Answer, the difference between two dates in Months is, **92** *(when current date is 22/04/2018).*